# Abrir archivo de Excel desde visual studio.net

Tags: vb.net

Cordial saludo, estoy intentando abrir  mediante un form, con varios botones, diferentes archivos de Excel, pero siempre sale el sgte error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Pongo el sgte código en cada botón

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/xxx.xlsm")
```

Gracias de antemano, cómo puedo solucionarlo???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el error completo, lo googleaste?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
Dim proceso As Process = New Process()
    proceso.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\TuArchivo.xlsx")
    proceso.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    proceso.Start()
```

Originalmente esta en C# aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application

de la respuesta de Mehdi Dehghani.
Funciona en .NET

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, al fin encontré solución... Funciona OK...

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido, no olvides marcar como respuesta por favor.